# Find minimum cost cycle in an undirected graph which cover some given specific vertices but starts and ends with normal vertex

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal, graph-coloring

Given a graph G=(V,E) and S is the set of vertices such that S is subset of G(V). Find out a minimum cost cycle in G such that it starts and ens from any vertex from set G(V)-S and covers all vertices present in set S.

Comment: Sounds a lot like TSP on S, at least if you're talking about simple cycles.

Comment: it is like variation of TSP